# Question about tab control

Tags: c#, t-sql, tabs

I am creating an app that that uses a tabbed view. I pull data from a sql database and display it in a grid. i want to be able to allow the users to add, edit, delete, etc on each tab. Is there a way to have add, edit, and delete buttons that show up on each tab without having to code it into each tab individually? Let me know if more info is needed. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either put the buttons outside the tab control and apply them to the currently selected tab, or have each tab display a control derived from a base class that includes the buttons (so they are only implemented once in the base class).

Comment: Leaving the buttons outside of the tab control seems to be the easiest way to do this. And then I can make only the selected tab update correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can move these buttons outside tab.

or

You can write a control that will contain these add, delete, edit etc buttons and then you can use this control in each tab.